# The number of ways to order books

Tags: combinatorics

What the number of ways to order 7 copies of the same book in three tables?

My turn:
$$1$$ The ways represent an order of 7 identical things in 3 different places, then the number of ways is 
$$C^{7+3-1}_{3} = 84$$
Is the solution correct ?

Comment: Almost.  You may have confused yourself looking at formula sheets and seen a very similar formula written but where the roles of $n$ and $r$ were reversed.  See [this related question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3092645/why-is-the-formula-for-combinations-with-repetition-equal-to-n-k-1-choos/3092654#3092654).  It will be $\binom{7+3-1}{3\color{red}{-1}}$

Comment: It would be better to say "What is the number of ways to distribute $7$ copies of the same book to three tables?"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your answer is not correct because by JMoravitz.

We can the formula can be deduced by changing the question to

> The ways represent an order of $(7+3)$ identical things in $3$ different places with at least one thing in each place.

And the answer is that there is $(7+3-1)$ place to seperate the things and $(3-1)$ seperators. Then there are $\binom{7+3-1}{3-1}=36$ ways.